# Change location of EditingAccessoryView in Custom cell

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'd like to move the location of the EditingAccessoryView in my cell. I've tried the following with no success:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView activityIndicator = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray);
activityIndicator.Frame.X = 227f;
cell.EditingAccessoryView = activityIndicator;
```

I'm doing this in the GetCell method.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

What about ?

```
cell.editingAccessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

explained:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.editingAccessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
     }
return cell;
}
```